# How do I render user uploaded html file as a page? Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-admin

This is the views.py

```
def datacategory(request):
  book = models.notebook.objects.filter(category='Students')
  return render(request,'datasets/students.html',{'notebooks':book})

class DataDetailView(generic.DetailView):
   model = models.notebook
   template_name = "datasets/data_detail.html"
```

data_detail.html

```
{% block body %}
<div style="padding: 2rem;">
   {{ notebook.noteb }}
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

models.py:

```
class notebook(models.Model):
  noteb=models.FileField(upload_to="notebooks/")
  category=models.TextField(default="")
  objects = models.Manager()class
```

The detail views are working but its just outputting the file name of the uploaded html file. How do I render the contents as a webpage?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read your uploaded `html` file, then render it as `string`. To do that, you can use the [`codecs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) and [`mark_safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe) modules. For example I use the `templatetags` to handle this, e.g:

## Optional 1

**File: `yourapp/templatetags/html_tags.py`**

```
import os
import codecs
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def read_html_file(html_field):
    html_path = html_field.path
    if os.path.exists(html_path):
        html_string = codecs.open(html_path, 'r').read()
        return mark_safe(html_string)
    return None
```

To use it in your template;

```
{% load html_tags %}

{% block body %}
  <div style="padding: 2rem;">
    {{ notebook.noteb|read_html_file }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**Update:** *If you want to validate only user logged in can see;*

```
{% load html_tags %}

{% block body %}
  <div style="padding: 2rem;">
    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}  <!-- add this -->
      {{ notebook.noteb|read_html_file }}
    {% else %}
      <p>You must logged in to see.</p>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

## Optional 2

If you don't want to use the templatetags, you can also handle it at your `models.py` file by creating new function/method to render it.

```
import os
import codecs
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class notebook(models.Model):
    noteb = models.FileField(upload_to="notebooks/")
    ....

    def render_notebook(self):
        html_path = self.noteb.path
        if os.path.exists(html_path):
            html_string = codecs.open(html_path, 'r').read()
            return mark_safe(html_string)
        return None
```

and then, you can directly call it to your template by following;

```
{% block body %}
  <div style="padding: 2rem;">
    {{ notebook.render_notebook }}
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thanks a ton! the first option works perfect.  Do you know how I can check if the user is logged in before rendering the html file?